# Как отсортировать массивы по заголовку, используя в это второй массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, как форматировть **Первый массив** по условию совпадения в строке значения `post_title` из **Второго массива** так, чтобы можно было в последствии вывести *комоды* в один блок, *консоли* во второй (простите за такое дилетантское объяснение)?

**Первый массив**

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [post_title] => Консоль из нержавеющей
        )

[1] => Array
     (
         [ID] => 2
         [post_title] => Комод из неражавеющей
     )
```

**Второй массив**

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Консоль
   [1] => Комод 
)
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример того, что вы хотите видеть в результате.

Comment: циклами, циклами, первый цикл перебирает array2, вложенный перебирает array1 на предмет соотвествия заголовка, например функцией stripos()

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = [
    ['ID' => 1, 'post_title' => 'Консоль из нержавеющей'],
    ['ID' => 2, 'post_title' => 'Комод из неражавеющей']
];

usort($arr, fn ($x, $y) =>  $x['post_title'] <=> $y['post_title']);

var_dump($arr);
```

[Запустить](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/039aa937481a8295b94f0bcd394272b4a202e00b)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(2)
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(40) "Комод из неражавеющей"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(1)
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(42) "Консоль из нержавеющей"
  }
}
```